# Radio button to Prevent to be checked after on click

Tags: javascript, radio-button, prototypejs, dom-events

I am trying to prevent a radio button not to be checked if a false is returned from the onclick.
Following is the jsbin link for the code I am using.
http://jsbin.com/oruliz/2/

Is there anything I am missing; BTW, I am trying to use JS with no framework.

However, if pure js has this issue is there a workaround for prototyoe.js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function propertyDamageType_click(elem) {
    if(yourconditionfails){ // or if(yourconditionfails && !elem.checked)
       elem.checked = false;
       alert('Please select an incident type');
    }
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wm5ZB/)

Answer (score 1):

You should user `return propertyDamageType_click()` .
See the http://jsbin.com/uvopek/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag and return false whenever the pre codition is not met....

```
 var IsIncidenntTypeSelected = 0;    // flag - sets to 1 when pre condition is met 
 $("input[type='radio']").click(function()
 {
       if(IsIncidenntTypeSelected  == 0)
            return false;
 }
```